# iOS File Sharing Alternatives to iTunes (UIFileSharingEnabled)

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes, file-sharing

Most of the sources explain file sharing in app bundle/document folder by using `UIFileSharingEnabled` option set as `YES` in `.plist` and locating app in iTunes `Apps` section. I'm wondering if there's any other alternatives to that?
Device is not relevant for this issue; it may be iPhone or iPad

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to share specific file types?  Are there features you would like that iTunes doesn't support?

Comment: it's simply .log file of application I'd like to import from desktop while device is connected, iTunes is okay for that but I'm curious about if there's alternative

Comment: Xcode's device window will let you copy the app's container area to/from a connected computer.

Comment: thanks it's helpful, I'd like to know if there's more alternatives

Comment: You can import documents from other apps too with a nice ui provided by the OS, but I'm not sure if that's what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So besides iTunes there's a path for Xcode that I'd like to express:

#### **Use Xcode**

- launch Xcode
- connect device
- from upper panel, select `Window` > `Devices`
- select connected device from left panel
- locate the IDESv2Sample from "Installed Apps"
- select "Settings" button at bottom
- select "Download Container" and "Save"
- locate downloaded "com.idscanbiometrics.IDESv2Sample .xcappdata"
- right-click and select "Show Package Contents"
- navigate through `AppData` > `Documents` for `log` directory